# acts_as_taggable_on and auto_complete returning no results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using acts_as_taggable_on in a model, and am trying to implement the auto_complete plugin. It seems as though I have everything hooked up correctly, but the search isn't returning any results. Here's what I have so far:

In the view:

```
<%= text_field_with_auto_complete(:link, :tag_list, {}, {:tokens => ','}) %>
```

In the controller:

```
  def auto_complete_for_link_tag_list 
    @tags = Link.tag_counts_on(:tags).where('tags.name LIKE ?', params[:link][:tag_list]) 
    render :inline => "<%= auto_complete_result(@tags, 'name') %>", :layout => false 
    logger.info "#{@tags.size} tags found."
  end
```

The logger keeps returning 0 tags, and nothing shows up in the view (yeah, the layout includes the javascript defaults). The SQL that is being generated looks like:

```
SELECT tags.*, COUNT(*) AS count FROM "tags" LEFT OUTER JOIN taggings ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id AND taggings.context = 'tags' INNER JOIN links ON links.id = taggings.taggable_id WHERE (((tags.name LIKE 'so') AND (taggings.taggable_type = 'Link'))) GROUP BY tags.id, tags.name HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Any thoughts or advice would be awesome.

Comment: It turns out the issue was a conflict with vestal_versions, which also has a tags model. there's a fork that someone made of vestal_versions to fix this: http://github.com/dfurber/vestal_versions/commit/61d786c9371d835b03a23c28cfb9e03322832863

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem and just ended up writing my own SQL, yours may look something like this:

```
@tags = Tag.find_by_sql("SELECT tags.name, tags.id
FROM tags JOIN taggings ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id 
JOIN links ON taggings.taggable_id = links.id 
JOIN groups ON links.group_id = groups.id 
WHERE groups.id = X
AND tags.name LIKE '%?%'",params[:link][:tag_list])
```

Youll need to update the groups.id = X portion, as I'm not sure how you are grabbing the group_id.

Tag is a class that the plugin provides, manually providing sql like this gives you all the flexibility in the world.

Answer (score 1):

You can also build a similar query using `ActiveRecord`

```
def self.tagged_like(term)
  conditions = ["taggings.taggable_type = 'Link' AND LOWER(tags.name) LIKE ?",
                "%#{term.downcase}%"]

   ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(:all,  
                              :include => "taggings", 
                              :conditions => conditions)
end
```

This generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT [..fields..] FROM "tags" LEFT OUTER JOIN "taggings" ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id 
WHERE (taggings.taggable_type = 'Link' AND LOWER(tags.name) LIKE '%something%')
```

**AATO version 2.0.6**